# Writing a Post Request in Express to make a List with given variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I am trying to figure out how to make a list using a Post Request through Express. I'm retrieving Video Game data through an api and I'd like to use the data I get there and add specific aspects to a list.
For example:

```
let name = localStorage.getItem("name");
let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
let cover = localStorage.getItem("cover");
fetch("http://localhost:3000/genre?search=" + id, {})
        .then((response)=>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((response)=>{
            let GenreHelper=[];
            for(let n=0;n<=response.length;n++) {
                GenreHelper[n]=response[n]["name"];
                document.getElementById("genre").innerText=GenreHelper.toString();
            }
        });
```

here I am getting id, name, cover and genres of a specific game and I'd like to give the name and cover over as a variable to a new html site to make a list.
I coded a button into my html to test the Post action

```
<form id="form" action="/addtolist" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I used a simple Post request to see if it works.

```
app.post('/addtolist',(req,res)=>{
console.log("Test");
});
```

This does work but I have no idea how I can use the Post request to grab the variable name for example and pass it onto a new html page or into a new javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but don't have enough points to do that. However, post data is usually found on the req.body. From your html it does not look like you are sending any parameters though. If you are using `express` install `body-parser`

```
//in app.js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies

//then in your route
app.post('/addtolist',(req,res)=> {
  const name = req.body.name; //req.body contains the values you send
  const id = req.body.id;
});
```

You need to make sure you are sending values though which you are not yet doing. 
You can use `fetch` like in your GET example and send a POST on button click.

Comment: You do not need body-parser now. You can do this: app.use(express.json())

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyhow. My Question is do you have an example how I could send a value through to the endpoint? I have been trying around with sending the "name" variable from my js file to the api call, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Comment: @DeltaP If you are using fetch check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch . If you are sending it in a form `<input name="name" id="name" value="DeltaP">`